# How to configure Allure Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: allure

I have installed Allure Jenkins Plugin 2.10 on Jenkins ver. 2.24.

The [installation instruction](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Jenkins+Plugin#AllureJenkinsPlugin-configure-security) says to

> Configure Allure Commandline from "Jenkins Configure Page".
>   [image]

Jenkins even complains about missing Allure Commandline:

[image]

However, the only option related to Allure on `/configure` page I found was:

[image]

Where can I find update-to-date documentation for Allure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a [bug report in Allure](https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/issues/48) that says:

> Setting up the Jenkins-Allure Plugin in Jenkins 2.0 has changed from the instructions given in https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_jenkins. The instructions state that to setup the Commandline details to go to /configure however in Jenkins 2.0 this setup is done in /configureTools.

Comment: link `http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Jenkins+Plugin` not working